# Jboss eap 7 class unloading issues

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

We have recently faced some strange issue with Jboss EAP 7 when we deploy the changes which includes changes to one particular method argument.

After deployment when we're trying to access that method we're getting method not found error and its referring old code which has only one argument.

Can you any one help with this issue. Is this has anything to do with class unloading. Below is one issue referring to class unloading

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-4683

Answer (score -1):

We have also faced same issue probably it could be due to class unloading